# How can I write a simple JUnit test to test a REST Controller

Tags: java, rest, junit, controller

I would like test the *methodForTest* method.

I want to use JUnit for testing and not an integration test.

My Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hi")
@Api(value = "Servise")
public class MyController {
@PostMapping(value = "/hi/save")
    @ApiOperation(value = "inquiry")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "fail"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 501, message = "ok"),
    })
    public void methodForTest(@RequestBody String res) {
        MyService.save(dto.getPhoneNumber(res));
    }
}
```

My JUnit test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class MyControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MyController myController ;

    @Mock
    MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl;

    @Test
    void sendSmsCode() {
        Mockito.verify(...)
    }
```

What would be the best way for me to test this?

Any advice or help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could user Mockito.verify() to verify that the method MyService.save(...) was called

Answer (score 0):

Mockito.verify(myController,times(2)).methodForTest(ArgumentMatchers.any()); //in case it is called 2 times